# How to use Map/Reduce in Scheme?

Tags: mapreduce, scheme, procedure

So I have a homework assignment for my CS course covering Scheme procedures. We just started learning the language last week, so I'm lost on how to answer this. I know the map procedure can get the dot product of two lists, but I didn't think reduce was needed to get the product. Below is example code he gives that reverses a list along with the question on a function convolution and dot product. I am also confused on the equation of the list y and how to actually read it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
(define (reverse lis)   
       (if (null? lis)       
          '()      
          (append (reverse (cdr lis))               
                  (list (car lis)))))
```

Sketch a function convolution in Scheme that computes the dot product of a list x with the reverse of a list y:

[image]

You may use a map/reduce approach, iterate over the list and add each product using a recursive call, or use any approach you wish.

Comment: The reduce part comes from calculating the sum of the individual multiplications. It's more commonly called a fold in scheme.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably way to late, but here it is:

Basically Sigma in the equation can be calculate with reduce `(reduce + list-of-values)` but to simply sum all the items you don't need reduce because you can use `(apply + list-of-values)`. The map part can be use to calculate the list of numbers from two lists. NOTE that Scheme don't define reduce but you can use:

```lisp
(fold-left + 0 '(1 2 3))
```

where 0 is inital value

Map work like this:

You can pass single list:

```lisp
(map square (list 1 2 3))
```

But in fact map accept any number of lists as arguments:

```lisp
(map * (list 1 2 3) (list 3 4 5))
```

and this will return the list of 3 elements where 1st item in first is list is multiplied with first item in second list. So it's like joining two lists and return single list.

To get proper list as output you simply need to reverse the given lists and pass it as one of the argument with orgiginal list.
And then sum up the resulting list. You should write nice function for that:

```lisp
(define (dot l)
   ...)
```

Now you should be able to write the dot function yourself. Sorry but you will never learn if you will give the code itself. Everything is explained.